# Is there a difference between how two ampersands and a semi-colon operate in bash?

Tags: bash

If I wanted to run two separate commands on one line, I could do this:

```
cd /home; ls -al
```

or this:

```
cd /home && ls -al
```

And I get the same results. However, what is going on in the background with these two methods? What is the functional difference between them?

Answer (score 89):

The `;` just separates one command from another. The `&&` says only run the following command if the previous was successful

```
cd /home; ls -al
```

This will `cd /home` and even if the `cd` command fails (`/home` doesn't exist, you don't have permission to traverse it, etc.), it will run `ls -al`.

```
cd /home && ls -al
```

This will only run the `ls -al` if the `cd /home` was successful.

Comment: using of ```; ``` is a really dangerous (at least with rm command), for example ```cd /some/dir; rm -fr ./*```. So with such destructive operation you must be sure that you are in the right place before execute rm. The right command is ```cd /some/dir && rm -fr ./*```

Answer (score 71):

```
a && b
```

if *a* returns zero exit code, then *b* is executed.

```
a || b
```

if *a* returns non-zero exit code, then *b* is executed.

```
a ; b
```

*a* is executed and then *b* is executed.

Answer (score 16):

```
cd /fakedir; ls -al
```

Runs `ls` in the current directory because `cd /fakedir` will fail and the shell will ignore the exit status that is not zero.

```
cd /fakedir && ls -al
```

Because the `&&` operator will only continue if the previous command exited normally (status of zero), no `ls` operation will be performed.

There are other operators, such as `&` which will background a process. While often placed at the end of a command, it can be put in the middle of a chain.

Answer (score 4):

You can also join them together like an `if..then..else` for chaining command logic.

example:

```
ls file.ext && echo "file exists" || echo "file does not exist"
```